# get an idea about the definition of a side

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I need to get an rough idea about the definition of a side

I think in topology mobius strip has only one side
and a piece of paper has two side

my problems are

**(1)** if I take a paper and simply bend it as a **L** shape how many side does it have
is it 2 or 4?

**(2)** ok using a paper we can build one side object(mobius strip).
By using a paper can we construct an object that has more than two side without cleaving it (mathematically)?

Comment: By surface, do you mean "side"? The sentence "mobius strip has only one surface" is weird to me. I would say it has one *side*, not one *surface*.

Comment: oh, ok thanks. I will edit

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750252/are-there-surfaces-with-more-than-two-sides/757003#757003

Comment: There is no well accepted definition of a "side", definitely not for general topogical spaces. However if we consider manifolds with boundary then a side might be a connected component of the boundary. From that point of view a "piece of paper" as in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ has one side as well. On the other hand a cylinder $S^1\times [0,1]$ (which is constructed analogously to the Mobius strip, except for the twist) has two sides. So from that point of view the **L** shape has one side as well.

Comment: As for the other question: you have to precisely define what "construct without cleaving" means. For example consider again a piece of paper which is a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Now glue together $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ with $\{1\}\times[0,1]$ to obtain a cylinder $S^1\times[0,1]$ which has 2 sides. Have a look at one of the sides (being a circle $S^1$) say "upper". Square that circle. Now you can apply the same construction to the upper side splitting it into two. Thus together with the lower side you have 3 sides now. Applying the construction recursively yields as many sides as you want.